# Hadoop Group Settings for a User

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set file permissions in the hadoop cluster. I want to give group-wise permission for a folder so that it can be accessed by a particular group. I have set these permissions for the folder --

> drwxrwx---   - user1  group1          0 2016-01-21 01:18 /folder1

Now I want to access this folder1 with user2 which belongs to group1. As I have set the permissions to 770. I am assuming this should work. But I am getting an error while trying with user2 --

> ls: Permission denied: user=user2, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/folder1":user1:group1:drwxrwx---

When I checked the details for user2 in linux -->

> $ id -Gn user2
>
> > $ user2 group1 group2

While the groups in hadoop cluster for user2 after login to user2 are -->

> $ hadoop dfsgroups
>
> > $  hadoop user2

I cannot see group1 in hadoop dfsgroups for that user. Can I add that or is there something else I should do? Please suggest how I can give permission to user2 for accessing group1 files???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Done :). Need to add user2 to group1 in the Namenode machine not the client machine.